# Jquery Mobile - Recursos

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Olá, é possível usar apenas alguns recursos do jQuery Mobile? Eu gostaria, por exemplo, de usar o "transitions" dele apenas. É possível? Se for como fazer?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim é possível.

Basta fazer o download customizado nesse link: http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/